# Calculate expected values based on a text variable

Tags: sas

I want to calculate some expected values at each row of the following table:

```
proc sql;  
create table delete
       (t0avgStakeRank num,
        eventtime num,
        previousnode char(10),
bettors num);
quit;

proc sql;  
insert into delete                                                                                                                 
(t0avgStakeRank, eventtime, previousnode, bettors)                                                                                         
    values(0,1,' ',1000)
    values(0,2, 'L',500)
    values(0,2, 'W',500)
    values(0,3, 'LL',250)
    values(0,3, 'LW',250)
    values(0,3, 'WL',250)
    values(0,3, 'WW',250)
    values(0,4, 'LLL',125)
    values(0,4, 'LLW',125)
    values(0,4, 'LWL',125)
    values(0,4, 'LWW',125)
    values(0,4, 'WLL',125)
    values(0,4, 'WLW',125)
    values(0,4, 'WWL',125)
    values(0,4, 'WWW',125)
    values(0,5, 'LLLL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LLLW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LLWL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LLWW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LWLL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LWLW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LWWL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'LWWW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WLLL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WLLW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WLWL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WLWW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WWLL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WWLW',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WWWL',62.5)
    values(0,5, 'WWWW',62.5)
    values(1,1, '',1000)
    values(1,2, 'L',500)
    values(1,2, 'W',500)
    values(1,3, 'LL',250)
    values(1,3, 'LW',250)
    values(1,3, 'WL',250)
    values(1,3, 'WW',250)
    values(1,4, 'LLL',125)
    values(1,4, 'LLW',125)
    values(1,4, 'LWL',125)
    values(1,4, 'LWW',125)
    values(1,4, 'WLL',125)
    values(1,4, 'WLW',125)
    values(1,4, 'WWL',125)
    values(1,4, 'WWW',125)
    values(1,5, 'LLLL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LLLW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LLWL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LLWW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LWLL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LWLW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LWWL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'LWWW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WLLL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WLLW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WLWL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WLWW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WWLL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WWLW',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WWWL',62.5)
    values(1,5, 'WWWW',62.5);                                                                                                                                                                                                   
quit;
```

The calculation will be based on the 'previousnode' variable, two static variables: one with value 3456 (for example) and the other with probability 0.75 (for example) and the eventTime variable. I want to parse the value of the previousnode variable into a formula. For example, at the node 'L', the result will be 3456*(1-(0.75^2), because the eventTime is two and the result is a loss. At the node 'LWLW', the result will be 3456*(0.25*0.75*0.25*0.75) because there has been a loss, a win, a loss and a win in that other.

How can I do this without explicitly coding this up in a huge PROC SQL query? I could substring the last, next-to-last etc results by checking whether each of those strings is an 'L' or a 'W' and then multiply accordingly, but I feel like there might be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Why is eventtime=2 pnode=L probability squared, but eventtime=5 pnode=LWLW does not take into consideration the fact that it is at eventtime=5 but only has 4 previous nodes?

Comment: Apologies, that's a misktake on my part. Node 2 will be based on the proobabilty ^ 1, not 2 as I said above, as there has only been one bet by that stage and the expected value is just half the starting count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROC FCMP is probably your answer.  Depending on the answer you give for the comment above, this either will work or will need a little adjustment - but in general should be a simple approach.

```
options cmplib=work.funcs;
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.foo;
function calcodds(percent,results $);
  odds=1;
  do x = 1 to length(results);
    odds = odds * ifn(char(results,x)='W',percent,1-percent);
  end;
  return(odds);
endsub;
quit;
```

Using the previous dataset:

```
DATA FOO;
length previousnode $8;
percent=0.75;
DO t0avgStakeRank=0,1;
    DO eventtime=1 to 5;
        if eventtime=1 then do;
            previousnode=' ';
            output;
        end;
        else do;
            do _t = 0 to 2**(eventtime-1)-1;
                previousnode=translate(translate(trimn(putn(_t,'BINARY.',eventtime-1)),'L','1'),'W','0');
                odds = calcodds(percent,previousnode);
                output;
            end;
        end;
    END;    
END;
run;
```

You could use the function in SQL as well.